# What output does the following for statement produce in C?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, indefinite

I anticipated it would produce:

> 10 5 3 2 1

but instead it prints

> 10 5 3 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1...

Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 10; i >= 1; i /= 2)
        printf("%d ", i++);

    return 0;
}
```

2 is printed, then one is added making it 3, divided by 2 is 1. As 1 is equal to 1, 1 is printed and then one is added making it 2, divided by 2 is 0. As 0 is less than 1, the loop should end.

Comment: 2 divided by 2 is 1, not 0.

Comment: Try debugging the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `i` is 1, you print it with the `printf` statement. Then `i` gets incremented (via the `++` operator in your `printf` statement). Then `i /= 2` is performed, which results to `i = 2 / 2` which results to `1`. This satisfies your condition `i >= 1`, making it an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

When `i /= 2` becomes `1` then body of the loop will print `1` and increment `i` by `1`. This will never let the value of `i /= 2` less than `1` and hence the value of `i` and the loop will iterate infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

i keeps getting incremented to 2 and divided by 2 which produces the infinite loop.